# How do I center the posts in the widget I created?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

```
TextField textWidget(String text, IconData icon, bool isPasswordType,
    TextEditingController controller, TextAlign align) {
  return TextField(
    controller: controller,
    obscureText: isPasswordType,
    enableSuggestions: !isPasswordType,
    autocorrect: !isPasswordType,
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      labelText: text,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
      filled: true,
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 107, 107).withOpacity(0.7),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
    ),
    keyboardType: isPasswordType
        ? TextInputType.visiblePassword
        : TextInputType.emailAddress,
  );}
```

I created a widget called textWidget and it's;

```
child: textWidget(
  "Mail Adress",
   Icons.people_alt_outlined,
   false,
   _numberController,
   TextAlign.center),
```

I tried to add it like this. I call in textWidget;

```
(String text, IconData icon, bool isPasswordType,TextEditingController controller, TextAlign align)
```

I assigned all the values ​​as seen in the second code. However, this did not bring the articles to the middle of the label.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set the `main Adress` at center?

Comment: I think you wanted to write an mail address. Yes, I want to bring the mail address text to the middle of the label.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925230/vertically-centre-align-text-in-textfield-flutter

Comment: I saw this code and added it under textField. But it doesn't work for me. It does not bring the text to the middle of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `label` to place Text widget instead of `labelText`

```dart
  decoration: InputDecoration(
        label: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

```dart
 TextField textWidget(String text, IconData icon, bool isPasswordType,
      TextEditingController controller, TextAlign align) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: isPasswordType,
      enableSuggestions: !isPasswordType,
      autocorrect: !isPasswordType,
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        label: Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.white70,
        ),
        filled: true,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 107, 107).withOpacity(0.7),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0, style: BorderStyle.none)),
      ),
      keyboardType: isPasswordType
          ? TextInputType.visiblePassword
          : TextInputType.emailAddress,
    );
  }
```

Comment: !(label != null && labelText != null)
"Declaring both label and labelText is not supported." 
I get this error

Comment: Remove `labelText` and `labelStyle` , use only `label` as shown on this post

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [InputDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)